# Determine corner coords from a set of coords on a page Python / OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, registration, coords

Given a set of points, how can I determine which are the top left, top right, bottom right and bottom left (TL, TR, BR, BL)

These are coords of black squares as located on the below images. (4 down each side of the page)

Here are the coords (x,y) (origin 0,0 is top left):

```
[(147.68485399616046, 3304.5385975548143),
(168.3419544680192, 2336.686128749161),
(188.1491476566771, 1331.864619054719),
(211.6472437750393, 155.6040367158578),
(2216.6064720878203, 3330.396441392227),
(2233.7510405426237, 2363.6828015004367),
(2250.9856437171966, 1360.935679736544),
(2273.392518618822, 187.8742947415933)]
```

By sorting these along the x axis, I can take the top 4 and the 4 bottom 4 which gives me both columns one for each side of the page.

I then summed the coords pairs i.e. 147+3304 = 3451 and so on.. By sorting the coords on this summed value I can take the lowest value to be the coords for TL, and the highest for BR (as that will have the largest x+y combination)

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxXJd.jpg
```

This works OK, apart from when I encountered this set of coords:

```
     [(203.68919057903938, 154.66471253728272),
     (2264.8873935264055, 180.78268029528675),
     (987.6169366297244, 1156.4133276499006),
     (184.2811080835604, 1331.004238570996),
     (167.45816773667582, 2336.89386528075),
     (2236.836364657011, 2356.0815089255643),
     (150.94371083838226, 3304.3057324840765),
     (2223.8576991353148, 3323.427188913703)]
```

Which when processed as above gives me an erranous TR location of 987, 1156 rather than 2264, 180

```
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVp4f.jpg
```

So how do I programaticaly determine my 4 corner coords?

Note I have redacted these images but they still give the same outputs.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyMG5.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVp4f.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8ylN.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7Sw.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxXJd.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/837nR.jpg
```

Comment: Do you always know the resolution/size of the squares you are searching for in the images? If so, maybe template matching will be much easier. Also, one of the images has no squares at all. What result do you expect on that? How about the one that has the squares clipped (the whole square is not in the image)? Finally, and most importantly, I don't really see a description of a "problem" per-se. You are getting some results that you don't like but I'm not sure exactly what it is you do want. Can you give expected output (in a simple format) for each of the example images?

Comment: The size in the pdf is be 5mm square but these are printed and scanned in so there is a variation in the actual size of the square in the image.  There are 2 sets of 3 images, 1. input, 2. detected squares, and 3. transformed image based on the squares. The first output is skewed terribly because it has detected the TR square in the middle of the image - my question is how do I compute the 'correct' TR square location, so I can safely transform the image? The second set of images produces is the correct output. The actual output is the last image.

Comment: I have some advice that might make it more likely for you to get help. 1) Clearly lay out what you want to do. 2) Clearly identify both what isn't going the way you expected and what you do expect. 3) Most importantly in this case, isolate the smallest version of your problem that doesn't work. Probably it looks easy to you since you've worked on it, but that block of code is huge for stackoverflow and the program output is also huge. Anyone that wants to help will more or less have to grok the whole thing to see how to improve it. If possible, isolate the problem more.

Comment: I'm not trying to rip your question - I'd like to help but I don't have time to study the whole thing and additionally I still don't feel clear on which parts are working, which parts are not and what the expected results are. If you have a chance, please edit the question as-is (instead of posting a new one) and I'll try to take a look at it again. Or maybe somebody nicer than  me will solve it in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks  Obviously this is my first post to SO and I was evidently too verbose.   I just have re-wrote the question hopefully it is more succinct now.

Comment: Good update. I was actually thinking you needed help with the image processing part rather than just the sorting part.

Comment: Did the answer I posted work for you? By the way, if you want ideas on the box-identification part of your code, you might get advice or ideas on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an inefficient, but I think straightforward approach.

The basic characteristic of TL, TR, BL, BR is that they are the closest to each corner. If you take any set of xy points, then all you need to do is find the shortest distance to each corner.

The code below does exactly that with brute force (comparing all points to all corners). It can be copy-pasted to the interpreter. Since I don't know the extrema of your given images, I've had to get them based on the available points. You can skip that by providing the corners of the image itself.

---

```
ok = [(147.68485399616046, 3304.5385975548143),
      (168.3419544680192, 2336.686128749161),
      (188.1491476566771, 1331.864619054719),
      (211.6472437750393, 155.6040367158578),
      (2216.6064720878203, 3330.396441392227),
      (2233.7510405426237, 2363.6828015004367),
      (2250.9856437171966, 1360.935679736544),
      (2273.392518618822, 187.8742947415933)]
bad = [(203.68919057903938, 154.66471253728272),
       (2264.8873935264055, 180.78268029528675),
       (987.6169366297244, 1156.4133276499006),
       (184.2811080835604, 1331.004238570996),
       (167.45816773667582, 2336.89386528075),
       (2236.836364657011, 2356.0815089255643),
       (150.94371083838226, 3304.3057324840765),
       (2223.8576991353148, 3323.427188913703)]


def distance(xy1, xy2):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2) = xy1, xy2
    return ((float(y2-y1))**2 + (float(x2-x1))**2)**0.5


def fake_image_corners(xy_sequence):
    """Get an approximation of image corners based on available data."""
    all_x, all_y = zip(*xy_sequence)
    min_x, max_x, min_y, max_y = min(all_x), max(all_x), min(all_y), max(all_y)
    d = dict()
    d['tl'] = min_x, min_y
    d['tr'] = max_x, min_y
    d['bl'] = min_x, max_y
    d['br'] = max_x, max_y
    return d


def corners(xy_sequence, image_corners):
    """Return a dict with the best point for each corner."""
    d = dict()
    d['tl'] = min(xy_sequence, key=lambda xy: distance(xy, image_corners['tl']))
    d['tr'] = min(xy_sequence, key=lambda xy: distance(xy, image_corners['tr']))
    d['bl'] = min(xy_sequence, key=lambda xy: distance(xy, image_corners['bl']))
    d['br'] = min(xy_sequence, key=lambda xy: distance(xy, image_corners['br']))
    return d


def main():
    for xy_sequence in (ok, bad):
        image_corners = fake_image_corners(xy_sequence)
        d = corners(xy_sequence, image_corners)
        print '********'
        for k, v in d.items():
            print k, v

main()
```

---

Output:

```
********
bl (147.68485399616046, 3304.5385975548143)
tl (211.6472437750393, 155.6040367158578)
tr (2273.392518618822, 187.8742947415933)
br (2216.6064720878203, 3330.396441392227)
********
bl (150.94371083838226, 3304.3057324840765)
tl (203.68919057903938, 154.66471253728272)
tr (2264.8873935264055, 180.78268029528675)
br (2223.8576991353148, 3323.427188913703)
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to try this and it does work very well. I had to use      
        cv2.circle(frame, ( int(round(v[0])), int(round(v[1])) ), 12, (0, 255, 0), -1) within main()  to draw at the location as it complained about requiring an integer and not a float.